# How to validate a Joi object based on a field type

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have the following **Joi** object:

```
const Content = Joi
  .object({
    type: Joi.valid('contentType1', 'contentType2')
    value: 'validate with that certain type'
  })
```

Is there a way to validate the field **value** based on the value of the field **type**

Answer (score 1):

Got it by doing this:

```
const Content = Joi
  .object({
    type: Joi.valid('contentType1', 'contentType2')
    value: Joi
      .when('type', {
        is: 'contentType1',
        then: Joi.valid('Yey')
      })
      .when('type', {
        is: 'contentType2',
        then: Joi.valid('Yow')
      })
  })
```